# Program force close when debugging or running

Tags: android

Previously my program was working well on different sizes of screen and devices. After I added some buttons to x-large screen and edited the layout to be different for all screen sizes the device prompts me to force close the program when I run it on all layout besides x-large. What is the problem??

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //**********************1 inch is about 160dp*********************
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

     int width = display.getWidth();  
     //int height = display.getHeight();  

     //for different sizes of screens, set range of position of scrollbars
     if(width > 1200)
     {
         maxY = 325;
         minY = 275;
         maxX = 700;
         minX = 600;
         limitY = 210;
         limitY2 = 360;
         axisSelector = 1; //use x
     }

     else
     {
         //to be edited
         axisSelector = 0;
         maxY = 250;
         minY = 200;
         maxX = 500;
         minX = 400;
         limitY = 120;
         limitY2 = 270;

     }

    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.controlLayout);
    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    localBtDevice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLocalBtDevice);
    remoteBtDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstRemoteBtDevices);
    btStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBtStatus);
    txtCalibrate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCalibrate);
    txtCalibrate.setText(String.valueOf(calValue));
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (btAdapter == null) {
        btStatus.setText(" > Bluetooth not available!");
        return;
    }
    localBtDevice.setText("  " + btAdapter.getName());
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    Iterator<BluetoothDevice> device = devices.iterator();
    final String[] deviceList = new String[devices.size()];
    final String[] addressList = new String[devices.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
        BluetoothDevice dev = device.next();
        deviceList[i] = dev.getName();
        addressList[i] = dev.getAddress();
    }
    remoteBtDevices.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, deviceList));
    deviceSelected = "";
    remoteBtDevices.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id) {
            btStatus.setText(" > Connect to \"" + deviceList[pos] + "\"?");
            deviceSelected = deviceList[pos];
            addressSelected = addressList[pos];
            return false;
        }
    });

    btnBtAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBtAccess);
    if (BtConnected == false) {
        btStatus.setText(" > Disconnected.");
        btnBtAccess.setText("Connect");
    }
    else {
        btStatus.append(" > You are connected to \"" + socketEP.getRemoteDevice().getName()+ "\".");
        btnBtAccess.setText("Close");
    }
    btnBtAccess.setOnClickListener(ConnectRobotListener);

    btnCalLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalLeft);
    btnCalLeft.setOnClickListener(CalLeftListener);
    btnCalRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalRight);
    btnCalRight.setOnClickListener(CalRightListener);

    progressBarX = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBarHorz);
    progressBarX.setMax(200);
    progressBarX.setProgress(100);
    steeringText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSteering);

    progressBarY = (VerticalProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBarVert);
    progressBarY.setMax(200);
    progressBarY.setProgress(100);
    throtleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtThrotle);

  //***********************************************************************************************  
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
            button1count++;
            if(button1count % 2 == 0){
            button1.setText("Tilt Steer Enabled");
            selector++;
        }
            else{
            button1.setText("Tilt Steer Disabled");
            selector++;
            }
        }
        }
    });
  //************************************************************************************************** 
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
            steerCountLeft++;
            if(steerCountLeft % 2 == 1)
            steer--;
            if(steer < 0)
               steer = 0;
            if(steer < 30)
            {
                try {
                    int calDirection = (int)((30 - steer) - calValue);                          
                    if (calDirection < 0)
                        calDirection = 0;
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('L');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection);
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    steeringText.setText("L "+String.valueOf((int)(30 - steer)+" deg"));    
                    int steer1 = ( ((steer * 334) / 100));
                    progressBarX.setProgress(steer1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    int calDirection = (int)((steer - 30) - calValue);                          
                    if (calDirection < 0)
                        calDirection = 0;
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('R');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection);
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    steeringText.setText("R "+String.valueOf((int)(steer - 30)+" deg"));    
                    int steer1 = ( ((steer * 334) / 100));
                    progressBarX.setProgress(steer1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }

            }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
  //**************************************************************************************************  
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
            steerCountRight++;
            if(steerCountRight % 2 == 1)
            steer++;
            if(steer > 60)
               steer = 60;
            if(steer > 30)
            {
                try {
                    int calDirection = (int)((steer - 30) - calValue);                          
                    if (calDirection < 0)
                        calDirection = 0;
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('R');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection);
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    steeringText.setText("R "+String.valueOf((int)(steer - 30)+" deg"));    
                    steer1 = ( ((steer * 334) / 100));
                    progressBarX.setProgress(steer1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    int calDirection = (int)((30 - steer) - calValue);                          
                    if (calDirection < 0)
                        calDirection = 0;
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('L');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection);
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    steeringText.setText("L "+String.valueOf((int)(30 - steer)+" deg"));    
                    steer1 = ( ((steer * 334) / 100));
                    progressBarX.setProgress(steer1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }
            }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    //***************************************************************************
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
                move++;
            if(move > 100)
               move = 100;

            if(move > 0)
            {

                try {
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('F');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(move));
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    throtleText.setText("F "+String.valueOf((int)(move)+" cm/s"));
                    progressBarY.setProgress(100 + move);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('B');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(-move));
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    throtleText.setText("B "+String.valueOf((int)(-move)+" cm/s"));
                    progressBarY.setProgress(100 + move);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }
            }
            }


            return true;
        }
    });


    //**************************************************************************************
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     

            move--;
            if(move < -100)
               move = -100;
            if(move < 0)
            {
                try {
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('B');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(-move));
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    throtleText.setText("B "+String.valueOf((int)(-move)+" cm/s"));
                    progressBarY.setProgress(100+ move);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('F');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(move));
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    throtleText.setText("F "+String.valueOf((int)(move)+" cm/s"));
                    progressBarY.setProgress(100 + move);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }
            }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });




    //************************************************************************************
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
                move = 100;
                try {
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('F');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(move));
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    throtleText.setText("F "+String.valueOf((int)(move)+" cm/s"));
                    progressBarY.setProgress(100 + move);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }

            }

        }
    });


    //**********************************************************************************
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
                move = 0;
                try {
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('F');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(move));
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                    RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                    throtleText.setText("F "+String.valueOf((int)(move)+" cm/s"));
                    progressBarY.setProgress(100 + move);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                }

            }

        }
    });
    //**********************************************************************************
    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
                move = -100;
                try {
                        RoboController.outputStream.write('B');
                        RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(-move));
                        RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                        RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                        throtleText.setText("B "+String.valueOf((int)(-move)+" cm/s"));
                        progressBarY.setProgress(100+ move);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                    }

            }

        }
    });

    //************************************************************************************
    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {     
                steer = 30;
                try {
                    int calDirection = (int)((steer - 30) - calValue);
                        RoboController.outputStream.write('L');
                        RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection);
                        RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                        RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                        steeringText.setText("L "+String.valueOf((int)(steer - 30)+" deg"));
                        steer1 = (steer * 334) / 100;
                        progressBarX.setProgress(steer1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                    }

            }

        }
    });

    //**********************************************************************************
    // imageTouchPadHorz=( ImageView )findViewById(R.id.imageTouchPadHorz);
    // imageTouchPadHorz.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){







  //**************************************************************************************************  


    ((SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)).registerListener(
             new SensorEventListener() {    
                @Override  
                public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {  


                    if(button1.getText() == "Tilt Steer Enabled" && btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close")
                    {


                        if(axisSelector == 0)
                        {
                            xPos2 = -event.values[0] * 3;
                            xPos2 = ((xPos2 * 100) / 10) / 3; 
                            axis1 = xPos2;
                            yPos2 = -event.values[1];
                            yPos2 = yPos2 * 10; 
                            axis = yPos2;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            xPos2 = -event.values[0] * 3;
                            xPos2 = ((xPos2 * 100) / 10) / 3; 
                            axis = xPos2;
                            yPos2 = -event.values[1];
                            yPos2 = yPos2 * 10; 
                            axis1 = yPos2;

                        }
                        if(axis > 30)
                            axis = 30;
                        if(axis < -30)
                            axis = -30;
                        if(axis < 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int calDirection2 = (int)(-axis);
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('L');
                                RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection2);
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                                steeringText.setText("L "+String.valueOf((int)(-axis)+" deg"));
                                int xPos3 = (int)axis;
                                xPos3 = 100 + ((xPos3 * 334) / 100);
                                progressBarX.setProgress(xPos3);

                            }   catch (IOException e) {
                                btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            try
                        {
                            int calDirection2 = (int)(axis);
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('R');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection2);
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                            steeringText.setText("R "+String.valueOf((int)(axis)+" deg"));
                            int xPos3 = (int)axis;
                            xPos3 = ((xPos3 * 334) / 100) + 100;
                            progressBarX.setProgress(xPos3);
                        }   catch (IOException e) {
                            btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                        }

                        }

                        if(axis1 > 50)
                            axis1 = 50;
                        if(axis1 < -50)
                            axis1 = -50;
                        if(axis1 > 0)
                        {
                            try {
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('F');
                                RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(axis1 * 2));
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                                //throtleText.setText("F " + String.valueOf((int)(100-(axis1 * 2))) + " cm/s");
                                throtleText.setText("F " + String.valueOf((int)(axis1 * 2)) + " cm/s");
                                int yPos3 = (int)axis1;
                                yPos3 = yPos3 * 2;
                                progressBarY.setProgress(100+yPos3);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                            }
                        }

                        if(axis1 < 0)
                        {
                            try {
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('B');
                                RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(-axis1 * 2));
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                                RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                                throtleText.setText("B " + String.valueOf((int)(-axis1 * 2)) + " cm/s");
                                int yPos3 = (int)axis1;
                                yPos3 = yPos3 * 2;
                                progressBarY.setProgress(100+yPos3);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                            }
                        }

               }
               }
                @Override  
                public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {} //ignore
            },
            ((SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE))
            .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0),   
             SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


    //*************************************************************************************************************************
}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int xPos, yPos, action, actionCode;

    if (btnBtAccess.getText() == "Close") {         
        xPos = 0;
        yPos = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            xPos = (int)event.getX(i);
            yPos = (int)event.getY(i);


            if (xPos < 200) { 
                //switch(v.getId()){
                //case R.id.imageTouchPadHorz://original code(   
            //if (xPos > 0 ) {                                          //testing purpose not needed
                if (yPos > minY && yPos < maxY) {                           //original code (edited) 275 - 325
                //if(yPos >0 ){                                         //testing purpose not needed
                    //xPos -= 5;                                        //whats the purpose
                    if (xPos > 150)                                     //original is 200
                        xPos = 150;                                     //original is 200
                    else if (xPos < 2)
                        xPos = 0;

                    if (xPos < 75) {    
                        if(selector % 2 == 1){
                        //original is 100
                        //int calDirection..... is to calculate value for pcb
                        //RoboController.outputStream.write is to write value on LCD
                        //steering text is to display on android device
                        //progressBarX is to fill the bar with yellow colour
                        try {
                            int calDirection = (int)((75-xPos)/2.4 - calValue);                         //100 , 3.3
                            if (calDirection < 0)
                                calDirection = 0;
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('L');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection);
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                            steeringText.setText("L "+String.valueOf((int)((75-xPos)/2.4))+" deg");     //100 , 3.3
                            //extra calculation to completely fill the bar
                            //due to the change of value from 200 -> 150, 100 -> 75
                            //used *133/100 as xPos and progressbar is int
                            //1.33 as 75*1.33 and 150*1.33 is almost = 100, 200
                            xPos = (xPos*133)/100;                      
                            progressBarX.setProgress(xPos);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(selector % 2 == 1){
                        //all changes are same as above
                        try {
                            int calDirection = (int)((xPos-75)/2.42 + calValue);            
                            if (calDirection < 0)
                                calDirection = 0;
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('R');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write(calDirection);
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                            steeringText.setText("R "+String.valueOf((int)((xPos-75)/2.42))+" deg");
                             xPos = (xPos * 133) / 100;
                            progressBarX.setProgress(xPos);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
    //      }


                    //values are calculated and changed to suit the UI of my device.
                    //original difference between the max value of height and min value was 200
                    // mine is 
            //******************************************************************************************
            else if (xPos > minX && xPos < maxX) {    //orignal is x > 900    set the limit length of scroll 600-700
                    //i used 220 - > 350, but the increase in limit is for clearance 
                if (yPos > limitY && yPos < limitY2) {                  //original is y > 100   set the limit height of scroll
                    action = event.getAction();
                    actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
                    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    {
                        yPos = 285;                 //285 is the center of scrollbar    //original is 420
                        //yPos = yPos - 185;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (yPos > 350)             //original is y > 520
                        {
                            yPos = 350;             //min value of scroll bar
                            //yPos = yPos - 150;
                        }
                        else if (yPos < 220)        //original is y < 320
                        {
                            yPos = 220;             //max value of scroll bar
                            //yPos = 220 - 220;
                        }
                    }
                    //purpose of 1.5405 is when scrollbar value is 285, difference of 285*1.5405 - 339 must be at least
                    //or equals to 100 yet it cannot be too big. 99.9 or 100.1 will affect the max and min value of cm/s
                    //the maximum difference is made as 200 so as to make life easier when calculating and displaying
                    //the value on screen and the progressbar. 
                    //best to use simple multiplication factors of 200
                    yPos = ((yPos * 15405)/10000) - 339;     
                    if (yPos < 100) {
                        if(yPos < 1)            //this if is used to prevent forward 101 from coming out
                            yPos = 0;
                        try {
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('F');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(100-yPos));
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                            throtleText.setText("F " + String.valueOf((int)(100-yPos)) + " cm/s");
                            progressBarY.setProgress(200-yPos);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        try {
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('B');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write((int)(yPos-100));
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\r');
                            RoboController.outputStream.write('\n');
                            throtleText.setText("B " + String.valueOf((int)(yPos-100)) + " cm/s");
                            progressBarY.setProgress(200-yPos);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            btStatus.setText(" > Error sending data!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return true;
}


//**********************************************************************************************************![xlarge image][1]
```

[image: xlarge image]

[image: normal]

[image]

Comment: give us the code so we can tell what's the problem

Comment: Noone can know the problem without more information. Please include your layouts and logcat.

Comment: get back to the last working software. then add one element at a time. at every implementation step run and verify if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are referencing an element in code that may not be in the layouts other than x-large.  Check all your elements and their IDs.

Comment: All my layout are named as "main" Only in different folders

Comment: Yeah, but what about the IDs for the buttons and other items etc?

Comment: But does it matters if in smaller layouts I exclude some buttons?

Comment: If you exclude buttons in small layouts but reference them in code then that is what is throwing the exception.  You need to check if you actually find the button in code before you try and reference it for anything...